# How can I toggle animate a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried installing Jquery UI so that I could easily add animation to the `toggleClass` funciton, but it only animates when adding the class, and not when removing the class (or moving back left to it's original position).

```
jQuery('#menu').click(function() {
  jQuery('#wrap').toggleClass('move-right', 1000);
  });
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 22px;
   max-width: 1150px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 20px;
}

.move-right {
   left: 9%;
}
```

**So How can I get this to animate both ways?**

It's just a simple slide to the right, then back left. I thought jQuery UI would be easiest, but if I don't need it even better

Comment: It seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/aT5RM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a left position to `#wrap`

then change your `.move-right` selector to be more specific

```
#wrap {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 22px;
   max-width: 1150px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 20px;
   left:0;
}

#wrap.move-right {
   left: 9%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrcLy/

Answer (score 0):

You could try it by using a boolean and if the boolean is true try moving it the other way.
Then your code should be something like this:

JS:

```
var right = false;
jQuery('#menu').click(function() {
  if(!right) {
    jQuery('#wrap').toggleClass('move-right', 1000);
    right = true;
  } else if(right) {
    jQuery('#wrap').toggleClass('move-left', 1000);
    right = false;
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 22px;
   max-width: 1150px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 20px;
}

.move-right {
   left: 9%;
}

.move-left {
   right: 9%;
}
```

This basically checks whether 'wrap' has moved right on clicking the button. If not, it moves it to the right, otherwise, it moves to the left.

Comment: Thanks, but it was buggy. Wasn't removing classes when it should have been. Thanks for trying though, Greatly Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 transition to define a transition property (left) and time (1s), see: http://jsfiddle.net/m3sEn/1/ This doesn't require jQuery UI.

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    left: 0;
    transition: left 1s;
}

#wrap.move-right {
    left: 9%;
}
```